# Translate simple Perl script into Python that sends a response to client?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, apache, perl

I'm really new to Python and my goal is to have the Python script print something to the client, and then display this on my webpage.

Fortunately, I stumbled upon a small code snippet that does exactly what I want to achieve with Python - unfortunately it is written in Perl.

I was wondering if anyone out there could show me how to write the Perl script in Python?

Here is the link that has all the code: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php

Here is the Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI;

$query = new CGI;

$secretword = $query->param('w');
$remotehost = $query->remote_host();

print $query->header;
print "<p>The secret word is <b>$secretword</b> and your IP is <b>$remotehost</b>.</p>";
```

How could I say the same thing in Python?

Here is the HTML page too:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Ajax Example</title>
<script language="Javascript">
function xmlhttpPost(strURL) {
    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;
    // Mozilla/Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    // IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
            updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText);
        }
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring());
}

function getquerystring() {
    var form     = document.forms['f1'];
    var word = form.word.value;
    qstr = 'w=' + escape(word);  // NOTE: no '?' before querystring
    return qstr;
}

function updatepage(str){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="f1">
  <p>word: <input name="word" type="text">  
  <input value="Go" type="button" onclick='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost("/cgi-bin/ajaxTest.pl")'></p>
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import cgi
import os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()  # for troubleshooting

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
secretword = form.getfirst("w", "")
remotehost = cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_HOST"] if "REMOTE_HOST" in os.environ else os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"])

print "Content-Type: text/html"     
print # blank line, end of headers
print "<p>The secret word is <b>" + secretword + "</b> and your IP is <b>" + remotehost + "</b>.</p>"
```

Edit 1: How to list all environment variables.

```
for k in os.environ.keys():
    print "<b>%20s</b>: %s<\br>" % (k, os.environ[k])
```

Comment: When I run it, I get an error on this line: remotehost = cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_HOST"])    It says: <type 'exceptions.KeyError'>: 'REMOTE_HOST' 
      args = ('REMOTE_HOST',) 
      message = 'REMOTE_HOST'

Comment: You can check if the env variable is set, and I also added how to list all environment variables set on the cgi process.